# Shipping fees not get updated when quantity get increased in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, cart, shopping-cart, free-shipping

- In the admin configuration, I set a minimum order amount of free
  shipping is 1000 INR and flat rate shipping as 50 INR per order.
- In my cart page when I order a product below 1000 INR, the shipping
  fees get applied as 50 INR correctly and if order above 1000 INR the
  shipping applied as 0 INR(It's working fine).
- But the problem is when I update the quantity in the cart page from
  the product range from  **below 1000 to above 1000 INR the shipping
  charge not getting applied correctly(in this scenario only when
  refreshing the cart the shipping charge get applied correcctly)**.
- But vice versa when I decrease the quantity from above 1000 INR to
  below 1000 INR the shipping charge get applied correctly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When update the quantity shipping charge not reflected correctly
[image]

But after reload the cart page only shipping charge get reflected correctly
[image]

Comment: Hello @Arun, As per mention images I think there is one custom module you used for ajax QTY update either you did customization for that. So here you have look into your customization.

Comment: @Ravi I didn't use any custom module for quantity update

Answer (score 0):

i also need to implicate shipping rate ajax based. Any solution for above query?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/200050)